# C: Subscripted value is neither array nor Pointer

Tags: c, arrays, io

I'm working on some homework for an intro to C class, in which we must write a program that reads input from a text file that contains order information from a winery. I've got everything written out, but when I run it, the only thing that prints properly is "Winery #1:" and then the window errors out. I tried to print one of my arrays out at the end of the program to see what the problem was, and then I got an error that states:

```
|54|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer|
```

I understand what the error means, though I am not sure what I need to do to correct it. I believe I have properly declared my arrays and such, but I still get the error. This is the code I have:

```
int main () {
  //Creates the file pointer and variables
  FILE *ifp;
  int index, index2, index3, index4;
  int wineries, num_bottles, orders, prices, sum_order, total_orders;

  //Opens the file to be read from.
  ifp = fopen ("wine.txt", "r");

  //Scans the first line of the file to find out how many wineries there are,
  //thus finding out how many times the loop must be repeated.
  fscanf(ifp, "%d", &wineries);

  //Begins the main loop which will have repititions equal to the number of wineries.
  for (index = 0; index < wineries; index ++) {
    //Prints the winery number
    printf("Winery #%d:\n", index + 1);

    //Scans the number of bottles at the aforementioned winery and
    //creates the array "prices" which is size "num_bottles."
    fscanf(ifp,"%d", num_bottles );
    int prices[num_bottles];

    //Scans the bottle prices into the array
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < num_bottles; index2++)
      fscanf(ifp, "%d", &prices[index2]);

    //Creates variable orders to scan line 4 into.
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &orders);

    for(index3 = 0; index3 < orders; index3++){
      int sum_order = 0;

      for(index4 = 0; index4 < num_bottles; index4++)
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &total_orders);

      sum_order += (prices[index4] * total_orders);
      printf("Order #%d: $%d\n", index3+1, sum_order);
    }
  }
  printf("%d", prices[index2]);
  fclose(ifp);
  return 0;
}
```

I looked at some of the other answers on this site, but none of them seemed to help me with my problem. I get the sinking feeling that the answer is looking me in the face, but being the tired amateur coder I am, I haven't been able to find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `prices` is not declared as an array, neither is `orders` for that matter

Comment: Since you call yourself an amateur, some coding tips:  First, I wish everyone's code were this clear and well commented!  You'll find that comments are the most helpful when they describe your reasoning, rather than the code itself.  It's safe to assume that anyone reading your code understands the language; what they _can't_ do is see your thoughts.  It's also a good idea to document your assumptions and expectations, such as, "We get here only if we've run out of wine."

Comment: Name your variables descriptively: instead of `index2` and `index3`, consider `bottle` and `order`.  And, finally, consider using braces around the single-line body of a `for`, `while`, or `if` statement.  That way you won't cause an error when you add another line to the body and fool yourself into thinking the indentation will convince the compiler to do what you meant.  :-)

Comment: The error code *smells* like C, like the whole program. Are you sure that the question is C++?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Adam! And yes, I've got a great programming teacher who really drove the point home when telling us how important clarity is when writing code.

Comment: @David: The text says "Intro to C", so I'm gonna say "C".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
//Scans the number of bottles at the aforementioned winery and
//creates the array "prices" which is size "num_bottles."
fscanf(ifp,"%d", num_bottles );
```

to

```
//Scans the number of bottles at the aforementioned winery and
//creates the array "prices" which is size "num_bottles."
fscanf(ifp,"%d", &num_bottles );
//               ^
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two `prices` One is array inside the for loop and another is int outside the loop. So `prices[num_bottles]` is no longer there when you try to print it at the end, where only the int prices is there. Obviously, int prices can't used as `prices[index2]`.

Take out the prices from inside the for loop and put it at the top.